# main.js code (queryselector) breaking when element is Div ID but works fine with "img"

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

Please help!  Been going at this for days now.
I have an image on my website that is supposed to change to a different image using "onClick".
The code works as expected with queryselector("img") but not when using a div id for the img.

HTML Code:

```html
<body>

<!-- element i'm trying to retrieve -->
<div id="firefoxlogo">
    <img src="images/firefoxlogo.jpg" alt="My test image" />
</div>

<!-- javascript link -->
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

main.js code:

```js
const myImage = document.querySelector("#firefoxlogo");

myImage.onclick = () => {
const mySrc = myImage.getAttribute("src");
    if (mySrc === "images/firefoxlogo.jpg") {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "images/jonatan-pie-3l3RwQdHRHg-unsplash.jpg");
  }     else {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "images/firefoxlogo.jpg");
  }
};
```

Initially the element was just an "img".

1. I systematically removed html code blocks until the main.js code worked properly.
2. The problem seemed to be a div id i had for a logo earlier in the code (#logo)
   Once i removed that code block, the main.js code worked properly even when loading all other html code blocks (except the logo).
3. In order to be more specific with the queryselector, i created a div id for the image i was working on (#firefoxlogo), however even with all other code removed, the queryselector seems to not be able to find the specified element (#firefoxlogo).

For clarity:
If i remove the div id and inject the img directly into HTML and then have queryselector("img"); it works.
If i use the div id ("firerfoxlogo"), and use queryselector("#firefoxlogo"), it doesn't work.

When i compile the code, i am not getting any errors.

I have not yet learned how to properly use GitHub and since the files are all saved directly on my computer, i recognize that you can't run the code on your end to test, but hoping someone can see what i'm doing wrong based on the code shown.
Thank you!

Comment: `myImage.getAttribute("src")` - A `<div>` doesn't *have* a `src` attribute.  It "works" when you select the `<img>` element because you're expecting to interact with an `<img>` element.  What are you trying to accomplish by changing that?  Why do you want to *select* the `<div>` if the goal is to *interact with* the `<img>`?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#firefoxlogo > img")` would get you the `<img>` element directly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#complex_selectors details some complex selectors

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue is with the way you are selecting the image element using the querySelector function. When you use querySelector("img"), it selects the img element directly, whereas when you use querySelector("#firefoxlogo"), it selects the div element with an id of firefoxlogo, not the img element inside it.

To select the img element, you can use the querySelector function with the CSS descendant selector, which selects the img element inside the div element with an id of firefoxlogo.

```
const myImage = document.querySelector("#firefoxlogo img");
```

In this case the querySelector function selects the img element inside the div element with an id of firefoxlogo.

I hope this helps!

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!  
That solved it. Exactly what was happening. Just added all the code back to the site and it works perfectly. 
THANK you sooooo much!